# Using .snk's private key to sign arbitrary data

Tags: .net, strongname, private-key

I'm developing a .NET [package manager](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-componento/) and one thing that got me thinking is security.

Given that anybody can potentially upload an assembly to the repository, how do I verify that said assembly comes from a trusted source? For example, I'd trust `NHibernate.dll` much more if it was signed with a private key of guys from NHForge. To ensure this, all I'd have to do is to verify assembly signature with NHForges' public key.

Now, with that in mind, how can one establish this relationship (that this particular public key belongs to this particular person)? An idea I came up with is as follows:

- Project author creates an XML file which contains information about the project and about an author (name, email, etc)
- This XML file is signed with authors' private key extracted from a `.snk` file which is later used to sign the assembly itself
- Author uploads this signed XML file to the repository, where it gets checked and a relationship between an author and a public key is established

To implement this (is this a viable idea, BTW?), I need a programmatic way of accessing `.snk` files and reading PK. Is there something for this in .NET?

Comment: Well, seeing as how strong names aren't guaranteed to be uncrackable, and that MANY assemblies people use daily are NOT strong-named (like the EF), I think you have much bigger problems than establishing a trust relationship with a project author.

Comment: @Will True, but with this infrastructure in place I'll at least be able to ensure that someone uploading `NHibernate.dll` is indeed from NHForge, and the assembly itself can be left unsigned.

Comment: LOL Anton, I think you've been beaten to the punch:  http://nupack.codeplex.com/ Not sure if that's 100% what you're envisioning.  Check on Hanselman's blog.  I think it'll be on scottgu's soon as well.

Comment: @Will: This really freaks me out. Been doing this for almost a year now (http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-componento/), but here comes Microsoft ans for obvious reasons my (and others' projects) may well be dumped. Sigh.

Comment: I feel for you. I had an idea for a website where people could have friends, press "like" buttons and have fake farms.  On a serious note, is yours better?  Perhaps there may be things you have learned that could be applied to nupack.  Or you may have a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

First off, strong names should **not** be used as a security mechanism—they are only intended to be used as an assembly identity mechanism. For something like this, I'd look into Authenticode, which was specifically designed for verifying the publisher/source of an assembly (i.e. security instead of just identity).

That being said, the idea you outlined wouldn't be feasible as-is because you can't strong name sign an XML file—strong name signing only works on .NET assemblies. Theoretically, what you could do is maintain some kind of mapping for each public key to a specific publisher (perhaps through a publisher registration process or something?), and then verify assemblies' strong name signatures before they are added to the repository.

As for the technical aspect, you can extract the public key from a `.snk` file via the [`StrongNameGetPublicKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5a7c9ad.aspx) function (which is part of the unmanaged strong naming API). You'll have to load the `.snk` file into memory yourself, though.